# RegX match up to &

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an Amazon URL that I'm trying to extract the seller ID from. The  URL format is: https://www.amazon.com/sp?ie=UTF8&seller=A3AQP8TDYVYCGL&asin=B0714K41PB&ref_=dp_merchant_link&isAmazonFulfilled=1&tag=odeo

And I want to extract A3AQP8TDYVYCGL

i.e. I want the seller=[THIS] up until the ampersand

I've gotten as far as the seller bit but don't know how to match up until the ampersand :(

```
 var regex = /seller=(.*)/;
 var url = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?seller=Ahg6qcgoay4'
 url = url.match(regex)[1]; // id = 'Ahg6qcgoay4'
```

I thought I could do $& and that would stop at the ampersand but clearly my regx knowledge is lacking :(

Comment: You mean like `seller=([^&]*)`?

Comment: `new URL('http://www.youtube.com/watch?seller=Ahg6qcgoay4').searchParams.get('seller')`

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/cDSJQU/1 ?

Comment: Any reason you don't use a standard parser for URLs?

Comment: @PM77-1 That won't work if `seller` is the first parameter, nor in the case it is not followed by another parameter. You should have suggested something like `[?&]seller=(?<id>\w+)(?:&|$)` instead.

Comment: URLs are complex - you'll either have to guarantee not all cases can happen, or need to consider things like username/password (`http://my:seller=haha@example.com?seller=realvalue`) protocols in urls, which are fully valid. That's not the only "whoops I forgot that can happen" in urls.

Comment: @logi-kal: Yes, you're right.